# Webpack Dev Server: route some root URL's to a external host

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app that I'm developing on localhost with webpack dev server.

There are `<a />` links in the app that reference urls that are outside of the app, but run on the same host of the app (once deployed).

So when I'm developing on localhost, if I click on one of these url's it takes to me `http://localhost:8080/not-part-off-app`, when I need it to take me to  `https://ourdomain.com/not-part-off-app`. I thought I could use the [dev server proxy functionality](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), but these URL's are all on the root and I can't seem to get it to work (tried a bunch of different configurations).  Most of them either return a `Error occurred while trying to proxy to: localhost:8080/not-part-off-app` when I click the link, or when the app loads as `http://localhost:8080/`

I'm thinking there has to be some way to get this to work, but I can't quite figure it out.

Code:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/': 'https://ourdomain.com'
    }
  }
```

Comment: wondering if it might be easier to use [setup](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-setup) to achieve this instead (and just regex for my redirected paths?)

Comment: Try this `proxy: {
        '/not-part-off-app': {
          target: 'http://ourdomain.com/not-part-off-app''
        }
      }` proxying `/` won't work I'm afraid. Cause this is where your app lives.

Comment: Even if it was possible to mount your app to some more specific route (which I'm not sure is possible), proxying `/` would capture everything.

Comment: @IvanYurov ya, I had to get a little more custom... Turns out the `before` configuration is good for this type of stuff.  Basically add middleware that can check the URL and redirect if needed (see solution below).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using the [before configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-before):

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    before: function(app) {
      app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        //do whatever to match url
        if(req.url.indexOf('/not-part-off-app') === -1){
          return next();
        }
        res.redirect(`https://ourdomain.com${req.url}`);
      });
    }
  }
};
```